# Loading css in python web app using jinja2

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2, wsgi

I'm trying to make a little bioinformatics web app. I had it working with CGI, I am trying to tweak it so I can serve it on pythonanywhere or heroku.

The problem I am having is that the stylesheet and javascript aren't loading.  I'm pretty new to programming, but I have searched extensively before posting.  I removed a lot of the heft from the app to isolate the problem. The app's directory now looks like:

```
/app
 main.html
 main.css
 main.js
 WSGI_app.py
```

The code in WSGI_app.py looks like:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import jinja2

def application( environ, start_response ):
    templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader( searchpath="./" )
    env = jinja2.Environment( loader=templateLoader )
    template = env.get_template( 'main.html' )
    template = template.render()
    start_response("200 OK", [( "Content-Type", "text/html" )])
    yield(template.encode( "utf8" ))

httpd = make_server('localhost', 8051, application)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

The top of main.html looks like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chimera Quest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</head>
```

I've tried replacing "./main.css" with "/main.css" and "main.css".

My browser's console reads:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8051/main.css".
```

Does anyone have see anything here?  I'm totally out of ideas.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using a WSGI server that also provides support for hosting static files, such as mod_wsgi with Apache, the best thing to do is to use a WSGI middleware to handle serving up static files. The main such WSGI middleware people use is called Whitenoise.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/whitenoise

Comment: Thank you so much Graham!  That did the trick.  I have so much to learn, especially regarding the server side of things.  I am working my way towards Apache and the like, at this point I'm just trying to spin up a little development server to work the kinks out of this app.  Also, in trying to learn how mod_wsgi/Apache handles this differently, I stumbled into your name.  Nice to meet you. Looks like I came to the right place!

Comment: By the way, on pythonanywhere, you actually don't need to use whitenoise to serve the static files. Just setup a static file mapping under the webapps dashboard and they will automatically offload static files to a separate thread that serves up files from the location specified (instead of tying up your own workers to serve the file).

Comment: Thanks Conrad! Good to know.  It seems I need to serve this particular app elsewhere, probably Heroku, because pythonanywhere won't let me shell out to run a java program, but I appreciate the tip.